# Vega-lite Legend for multi-field data

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I have data formatted with multiple fields per x:

```
x1 f1 f2 f3
x2 f4 f5 f6
...
```

This is so I can use tooltips with custom formatting (showing all the values for a single x) and so that I can customize the mark for each field. [link to sample](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5gkVgCcx2LTvR9kOvGOQiA7tZbIjdeLApqoAM25GMPDMDPABPQmQzSA8vAF9Y9QhIZCV4bk1GJWpgjSSAD2DIPEZUZABVJWYo0OsA5RZtPEjVX0ZkMU0oxuaoMIioptRCf3RTBNze7m4xYsIzAG0JiBCS8sqgnEga9DqlBp0eyB82jq6D7yLwyM3B4aNRyHGIZ7ADY-bOm7RCAH0MApal36mwAjqx0HtmDpGFRHokXq8jidPr1vn9Mhc+tcoGCIcVdMVYbEJgBdDRPKBidA1IwLUAvSAYIwAa0KWKiO2sFzSYn8URGWUiFKSKTSGSyOQRUFChXepy+Qz+6ABvSuUVxkIJMKFE2JEASrwmjJ2rP0QOxkAkSkOPL5myMyE6wqgovSmWy+iW0tlyIGaNQGMB7NB4M10KJuvJLXpz2NLKiRlYdjURtg7WQ8GKyklCMgiG4VFpZuDUFg7uTgOzm1Q3FYaYLrgu3zCUSUyh1L2dyVSbolnql0WmdsNUqSaSUGSzKiwMdHpfTmZ408RbY2uAbtINkAoo1YFrw9yUsEInL2kC9+q9eue19iJPhg6Uxw9iOVjFgAE1CgGlABRPJNGeOAAMwAAzxCAxJAA).

I would like to add a legend to show the meaning of the colors, but I can't make one auto generate for the multiple fields. I was thinking of adding a second dataset with discrete values for the fields and colors (something like [this](https://observablehq.com/@vega/a-guide-to-guides-axes-legends-in-vega)), but apparently you can't add multiple sets to vega-lite, and I don't know enough to move to pure vega. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to generate a legend from multiple columns is to use a [Fold Transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/fold.html) to fold them into a single column, then let the encodings handle the legend for you. Modifying the example you linked to, it might look something like this: ([vega editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4zEgVwE4BsVTkQHoBnAUwXhzIFoB3C+ACzKwDoBjEgN0gBooAMwD2WALYJ86eAE8ADmXyQuvAL6q+4KGQB2HYdACWOgOZStESAA8pkeIbFkAqjsPwlMiuOE7mhRQKQgoZkONBK-vxQsgpK8GRicqKweBoW0cLCOPZy+ADa6RDSDs6u7qiQnrDevkyRgcGh4RX10fKKFfGJyamaEP1oQSFhcQlyAPoSNoExHVAAjhiwvm4IhtyKaQNFQ02jiZPGUXbtSovL9oj2G5Cq6QC6WltQOLCeWPnpoNvRWMskInEnx+OxEI1QeTsY0OOmOXQmU0g90CsBI+UgjlR2AC0TGSLuP2RhSgEiwAGtbLMlDhjJs+ttILp9EZTOYQVAZLZGuDcYk4acKucVld1nTiZZ9DhRFzhs0SRQSNj+bEKjphGJjClbsSCf1nkViRjqhSKlgMNR+IbyNQOPYfGyQZAmMINh9UNIBVASMYTBbAvaKmJhBhyC7WMcxrIlGqdJsdfSBoy9AYfQ6fsostL3eL+hmdEY7bD3ZBrWRbYYA4M1eUoM7XbdAtwUhg5nY-joSHJqrp3Lqfn29eldUSJT5gmZi7ArIYSABNWwanQAUSs8V8+AAzAAGdQgVRAA)):

```
{
  "data": {"url": "data/seattle-weather.csv", "format": {"type": "csv"}},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"timeUnit": "yearmonthdate", "field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "tooltip": [
      {"timeUnit": "yearmonthdate", "field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
      {"field": "temp_max", "type": "quantitative"},
      {"field": "temp_min", "type": "quantitative"}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "transform": [
        {"fold": ["temp_min", "temp_max"], "as": ["measure", "temp"]}
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "line"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "temp", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"field": "measure", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "rule",
      "selection": {
        "hover": {"type": "single", "on": "mouseover", "empty": "none"}
      },
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {"selection": {"not": "hover"}, "value": "transparent"}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {"axisY": {"minExtent": 30}}
}
```

[image]

Notice that we've replaced the two temp_min/temp_max layers with a single layer that transforms the data and encodes color by column name, automatically generating a legend.